# How to design a rating system which permits one vote per user considering the performance?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, rating

I am using Ruby on Rails\MySQL and I would like to implement a rating system with the following conditions\features considering a large amount of users and articles:

- Each article have 3 rating criterias
- Each criteria is a binary function (examples: good\bad, +1 \ -1, ...)
- Each user can vote *one only time* per criteria and per article

**I would like to know in those conditions what are the best approaches\techniques to design\think of the database (for exmple in UML) in order to ensure a optimal performance (response time of a database query, CPU overloading, ...).**

P.S.: I think a rating system as that working for the Stackoverflow website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a table for the ratings:

```
CREATE TABLE vote
        (
        userId INT NOT NULL,
        articleId INT NOT NULL,
        criterion ENUM('language', 'usefulness', 'depth') NOT NULL, -- or whatever
        value BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (userId, articleId, criterion)
        )
```

This will allow each user to cast at most one vote per article per criterion.

`criterion` has type `enum` which allows only three different criteria. This constraint is on metadata level: this means that if you want to add the criteria, you will have to change the table's definition rather than data.

Comment: And if I create a table to store each vote for each criteria (that is, create 3 tables, one per criteria), there will be a performance improvement?

Comment: @user: depends on the queries. For instance, this won't allow you to build the SO-style activity list easily and efficiently (with votes on all criteria ordered in a single list).